# How to retrieve try/catch error

Tags: javascript

how can I find the error

```
try {
    undef
} catch (e){
    console.log(e)
    console.dir(e)
}
```

the information bust be there somewhere, because the console.log (in firebug) includes:

```
ReferenceError: undef is not defined
```

but when I browse the `e` object, I can't find it.

How do I find out what the error is programmatically, so I can handle the error accordingly?

Edit:
[image: screenshot showing error object]

Comment: In my browser it's right there, in `type`: "not_defined", and `arguments` is an array w/ element 0=`"undef"`. Are you referring specifically to exceptions you're not generating?

Comment: I added a screenshot - does yours look anything like that? I am on OSX using firefox 13.0.1 and firebug 1.10.2

Comment: @BillyMoon this is what I see in Chrome dev tools http://i.stack.imgur.com/E3O34.png

Comment: Are the error objects returned to catch standard across browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {

    if(typeof undef  == 'undefined'){       
        console.log('We should not access this "undef" var');
    }       
    console.log('The next line will produce an exception');
    undef
} catch (e){
    console.log(e);
    for(index in e){
        console.log(index+' ('+(typeof e[index])+'): '+ e[index]);
    }
}
```

---

Which will produce:

---

```
We should not access this "undef" var
The next line will produce an exception
ReferenceError: undef is not defined
fileName (string): file:///B:/xampp/htdocs/study/test.html
lineNumber (number): 12
stack (string): @file:///B:/xampp/htdocs/study/test.html:12
```

Comment: Please add the `e.toString()` to this answer for completeness

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pull its type explicitly, but you can test it:

```
try {
    undef
} catch (e){
    console.log(e)
    console.dir(e)
    if(e instanceof ReferenceError) {
      console.log("Ooops! Fat fingers!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But of trial and error gives me this...

```
try {
    undef
} catch (e){
    console.log(e.toString())
    // ReferenceError: undef is not defined
}
```

I guess firebug is just accessing the `.toString()` method of `e`

---

Edit:

I am guessing the `.toString()` method just concatenates the only two properties that are guaranteed cross browser - `name` and `message` - so I think `e.message` is the only reliable and useful piece of information to go with.